# unable to upgrade my php in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, php

I am trying to update my php from 5.3.10-1~lucid+2uwsgi2 (cli) to 5.4, but getting error. I am trying with the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

but getting the error:

```
Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ondrej/+archive/php5: couldn't connect to host
```

Could you please suggest how to do my update?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this doesn't technically solve your problem, but 10.04 is really old. Perhaps consider upgrading to a newer/supported version of ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you do:

Inside `/etc/apt/sources.list` we add

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu lucid main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu lucid main
```

And then we add his key and update the system

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E5267A6C
apt-get update
```

Now, we can get the new PHP5.4!

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Founded on https://gist.github.com/terwey/6416511

> **EDIT**
>   Seems like the package is not longer available as there is no more support for Ubuntu 10.04. See post https://askubuntu.com/a/419462/189996 and the comments.

Comment: and don't forget to remove the other repository from your source.list...

Comment: I am getting gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error when run the apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E5267A6C command 
Also please mention which repository I need to remove from source.list.

Comment: If you execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5` it had added 
`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu lucid main `

`deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubunt lucid main `

This lines you should remove...

Comment: About the key. If you hit `apt-get update` it should show you which key is missing... you can check manually if the key exists: http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Just found this: http://askubuntu.com/a/419462/189996

Comment: if I run the command apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
it is showing the follwoing error:
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.2kXRNHJSoC --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

Comment: check the error output of `apt-get update`! It usually shows you which key you need to go for...